# categorize records in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am wondering if it is possible to categorize records in BigQuery.

For example;

```
number - site - visits
1-A-10
2-B-20
```

I would want to take Site A and B and create a group call "Cars". Can someone please tell me how this is done?

Comment: As phrased, the answer to your question is "yes", but beyond that, I think the question is too broad.  Please provide more details . . . are you looking for a query?  Are you looking for a data model?  What are you looking for?

Comment: Just add a new table? Check out Database Normalization ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization))

Comment: @gordon-linoff i have updated the question. I am actually looking for a query

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking  - please be more specific!

Comment: @mikhail-berlyant I am trying to create channel grouping in Bigquery. For example i want to create a group call "Social" for the source Facebook.

Comment: in your question  - you need to be more specific and explain what exactly it means for you "create a group". so far - it is absolutelly not clear and rather very abstract - i doubt anyone can answer this question as it is right now

Comment: @mikhail-berlyant if you look in my example, i have data for site A and site B and i am trying to create a new group call "Cars" and sum of visits would be 30.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the best I can think of based on your comments to your question
Hope it is what you asked for

```
SELECT
  CASE 
    WHEN site IN ('A', 'B') 
    THEN 'Cars' 
    ELSE 'Others' 
  END AS category,
  SUM(visits) AS visits
FROM
  (SELECT 1 AS number, 'A' AS site, 10 AS visits),
  (SELECT 2 AS number, 'B' AS site, 20 AS visits),
  (SELECT 3 AS number, 'C' AS site, 50 AS visits)
GROUP BY 1
```

Added example for [CASE WHEN](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#otherfunctions) statement

```
CASE 
  WHEN (Medium = "A" and source = "facebook.com" ) THEN 'Social' 
  WHEN (Medium = "B" and source = "facebook.com" ) THEN 'PaidSocial' 
END as Category
```

Comment: yes, i was able to use this and create my query. Thank you.

Comment: i just added example to answer, but great that you got it by yourself :o)